# Why does Bibtex Fail?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, overleaf

I'm using bibtex and I included the following code:

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{refs.bib}
```

In the same folder I added the file `refs.bib`:

```
@book{texbook,
  author = {Donald E. Knuth},
  year = {1986},
  title = {The {\TeX} Book},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley Professional}
}

@book{latex:companion,
  author = {Frank Mittelbach and Michel Gossens
            and Johannes Braams and David Carlisle
            and Chris Rowley},
  year = {2004},
  title = {The {\LaTeX} Companion},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley Professional},
  edition = {2}
}
```

But when I compile, no reference appears. What mistake did I make?
Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Did you use `\cite{}` in the document?

Comment: I didn't. That solves the problem! Thank you!

Comment: Don’t use the extension `.bib` in the argument to `\bibliography`: just `\bibliography{refs}` is the correct way.

Comment: Can I ask one more question: I used `hyperref` and the resulting references, e.g. [1], [2], [3], are unclickable: they don't direct the readers to the reference section. How can I resolve this issue?